Register Hook to Intermediate Nodes in PyTorch
Imagine you have something simple like this:
import torch

x = torch.tensor([4.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad=True)
output = x * y + x / y

grad_x = torch.ones_like(output)
torch.autograd.grad(output, x, grad_outputs=grad_x)

which results in a computational graph like this:

Now I'd like to access the gradients of the intermediate nodes i.e. MulBackward0, DivBackward0 and AddBackward0. I know that PyTorch doesn't store it by default. I know I I can make it explicit and then define retain_grad etc.
But is there the possibiltiy of just attaching a hook to any of those nodes without having to loop through the graph etc.?

In PyTorch, you can register hooks to modules (and tensors, incidentally), for backward (respectively forward) passes, to operate on their gradient (respectively output).
You could wrap the multiplication and division operations in separate modules and hook on them.
Something like
from operator import mul, truediv

import torch


class Mul(torch.nn.Module):
    forward = mul


class Div(torch.nn.Module):
    forward = truediv


def hook(module, grad_input, grad_output):
    print(f'in module: {type(module).__name__}, {grad_output=}')


mul = Mul()
div = Div()

mul.register_full_backward_hook(hook)
div.register_full_backward_hook(hook)

x = torch.tensor([4.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad=True)

output = mul(x, y) + div(x, y)

grad_x = torch.ones_like(output)
torch.autograd.grad(output, x, grad_outputs=grad_x)

